# yii Rest api Authentication iOS app

Tags: php, ios, rest, authentication, yii

I've used [this tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/175/how-to-create-a-rest-api/#hh14) to implement a REST api for a Yii app. It works well but I need advice on the authentication part. In the tutorial there is a method to authenticate which receives the username and password (not encrypted) on 2 headers, and according to the tutorial I can use the same method to check the user data on every API call.

This is the code of the authentication method

```
private function _checkAuth()
{
    // Check if we have the USERNAME and PASSWORD HTTP headers set?
    if(!(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_USERNAME']) and isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_PASSWORD']))) {
        // Error: Unauthorized
        $this->_sendResponse(401);
    }
    $username = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_USERNAME'];
    $password = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_PASSWORD'];
    // Find the user
    $user=User::model()->find('LOWER(username)=?',array(strtolower($username)));
    if($user===null) {
        // Error: Unauthorized
        $this->_sendResponse(401, 'Error: User Name is invalid');
    } else if(!$user->validatePassword($password)) {
        // Error: Unauthorized
        $this->_sendResponse(401, 'Error: User Password is invalid');
    }
}
```

So I have the following questions:

1- Is it insecure to use this method given the fact that I send the password and username unencrypted?

2- Should I consider implementing Oauth2 for this? This API has only 2 methods I will use right now so I wouldn't like to spend much time on an extra authorization protocol if not strictly necessary.

Any help is very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP basic auth (the authentication method you use) is not something that can be *trivially* broken into, but it does send the authentication information over the wire in plain text, repeatedly, for every request.

This problem can be somewhat addressed by using HTTPS, which encrypts the data while it is being transported. But even then, there remain problems with HTTP basic auth. [This answer on Security.SE lists them:](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/988/is-basic-auth-secure-if-done-over-https)

> - The password is sent repeatedly, for each request. (Larger attack    window)
> - The password is cached by the webbrowser, at a minimum for    the length of the window / process. (Can be silently reused by any   other request to the server, e.g. CSRF).
> - The password may be stored    permanently in the browser, if the user requests. (Same as previous    point, in addition might be stolen
>   by another user on a shared    machine)

Whether it is secure enough really depends on the level of security your service requires. Is it a high score for a niche online game? It's probably fine. Is it an API that allows access to sensitive things? Then it may not be good enough, and looking at something like OAuth may be a good idea.

Comment: Okay thanks for taking the time, any advice on how to change to https?

Comment: It's not trivial - you'll need to get a certificate and get the server set up accordingly. You probably want to talk to your hosting provider or server admin